# hive jdbc throws "Error running query: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
FROM cr_expanded_crcs_halen c INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE merge_result SELECT 'crcs', operator_id, instance_id, ts, user, application, actualconn, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

I try to insert data to table merge_result using above sql with jdbc, found errors as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error running query: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:159)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:147)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:182)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.HiveClient.main(HiveClient.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

but the data has been inserted successfully.
Any body can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same error.
Unfortunately, I can't found why it's failing, but I found a workaround.
The problem occurs when you use the word NULL into a select statement thought JDBC, My ugly solution was replace NULL by an udf "null_value()"

I will open a jira with this problem

```
@Description(name="null_value", value="_FUNC() return null")
@UDFType(deterministic=true, stateful=false)
public class NullValue extends GenericUDF {


    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments)
            throws UDFArgumentException {
        return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector;
    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(String[] children) {
        return "keys_to_lower_"+children[0];
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Gabo